# Creating *.css.map files when minifying .css files

Tags: css, minify, web-essentials

I'm using VS 2014 Web Essentials.  Most of my CSS is compiled from LESS files, and Web Essentials creates *.css, *.min.css, and *.css.map files for those.

I've inherited quite a lot of plain *.css files, however, and when Web Essentials minifies these, it only creates *.min.css files--no *.css.map files.  Is there a way to change this behavior?

Comment: Visual Studio 2014 is not a version of visual studio (due to Microsoft changing their mind). Did you mean Visual Studio 2015?

Answer (score 0):

Try renaming your existing .css files to .less, then open and save the less file. If you have WE running it should create a css, css.map, and min.css for you.

Comment: Are you saying to tell .css.bundle files to compile to .less files which then compile to .css/.css.map files?

Comment: I don't know about Bundling, I haven't used that feature yet. I am saying that if you start with a .LESS file, then WE will create a .MAP file for you, but it doesn't appear to create the .MAP file when you are directly editing a .CSS file.

Comment: Ah.  `.css.bundle` files contain a list of .css files, then compile them into one large file (`.css`) and minimize that resulting file into a `.min.css` file.  The reason for bundled files is to minimize the number of files needed to be downloaded when it's always the same set of files, and thus improve client-side performance.  

Static `.css` are having their `.min.css` and `.css.map` files generated, as well as less-compiled `.css` files.  For some reason, bundles aren't generating the map files though.

Comment: I need to play with bundles. Currently I just separate my less files into sub files and include all needed into a master less file that is then minified and used by the page. I wonder what advantage bundles would provide.